# symfony forms: get a second attribute in label for a select element

Tags: php, symfony, jquery-select2, symfony4

I have an entity `Institution`. In a form a user can select one or more. I use Select2 for the font-end. An institution has the attribute `internationalName`, which is the default attribute because of:

**Institution.php**

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->internationalName;
}
```

An institution can also have an abbreviated name, as attribute `abbreviation`. What I would like, is to use this second attribute to show (if it exists) in the select form. Even better would be that it's not shown but that you can search for it, but I really don't know if this is possible at all.

I could change `__toString()` so that it includes the `abbreviation`, but this is unwanted because of other forms, so I am trying to make it show only in this form through

**LocationType.php**

```
->add('Institutions', EntityType::class, [
    'class' => Institution::class,
    'label' => 'Connected Institution(s)',
    'multiple' => true,
    'attr' => ['data-select' => 'true', 'data-placeholder' => 'start typing to find your institution...'],
    'constraints' => array(
        new Count(array(
            'min' => 1,
            'minMessage' => "Select at least one institution."))),
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('i')
            ->orderBy('i.internationalName', 'ASC');
    },
```

I tried to use `'choice_label' => 'abbreviation'` (just as a test), but that makes all labels *blank*, which I really don't understand why. I also tried `'choice_label' => 'internationalName'.'abbreviation'`, but that won't work because there is no property `internationalNameabbreviation`. I thought about creating a new attribute where I combine the two, but given that  `'choice_label' => 'abbreviation'` already results in a blank list I don't think this would work. Any other options or solutions?

edit: as requested the relevant entity class part, 
**Institution.php**

```
/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter the international name.")
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
private $internationalName;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 */
private $abbreviation;
```

Comment: Your entity has an "abbrevation" property ?

Comment: It has an 'abbreviation' attribute, yes, which is a string.

Comment: Can you post you entity class ?

Comment: @ThomasLefetz, I added the relevant part of the entity class.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-value

```
  ->add('Institutions', EntityType::class, [
    'class'         => Institution::class,
    'label'         => 'Connected Institution(s)',
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er
          ->createQueryBuilder('i')
          ->orderBy('i.internationalName', 'ASC')
        ;
    },
    'choice_value' => function (Institution $institution = null) {
        return $institution ? $institution->getInternationalName() . '(' . $institution->getAbbreviation() . ')' : '';
    },
  ])
```

Comment: With 'choice_label' instead of 'choice_value' this is a good option and I can show the abbreviation and search for it. Next step, if you have a suggestion for this as well, is to hide the abbreviated part to the user but still make it searchable.